# サーバーとデータの管理は開発者がするものですか？

Tags: swift, ios, firebase

バックエンドを持つアプリの場合、サーバーと保存されたデータは開発者が管理すると考えていいでしょうか？

サーバーはfirebaseの使用を想定しています。

Comment: よくありません。保守・運用を必要とするアプリの場合、それを誰がやるかはきちんと事前に決めておく必要があります。「バックエンドを持つアプリ」「サーバーはfirebase」と言うだけでは、普通はこうするといった情報は得難いでしょう。単に言葉の問題だけ言うと、通常、明確な合意がない限り「開発者」と「保守・運用の担当者」とは別物です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！私個人がアプリを企画して開発してリリースする、つまりクライアントがいない（私自身がクライアント）場合は、私自身がサーバーを保守・運用すると考えるのは妥当でしょうか？

Comment: あなた自身が「アプリを企画して開発してリリースする」場合でも、別の個人なり組織なりにサーバの運用を任せるのは十分ありえることですから、「妥当」かどうかは微妙ですが。とにかく「誰かがやらなくちゃいけないこと」は「誰がやるのか決めておくこと」が必要です。

Comment: なるほど、運用を他者に任せるケースもありうるのですね。ありがとうございます。